# Why cout and cin would pop up error when I use ncurses..?

Tags: c++, ncurses

Emmm...I am writing a code that it can read the user input immediately after user press the key...
and I found the code online:

```
initscr();
cbreak();               
noecho();               
scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);     
nodelay(stdscr, TRUE);
while (true) {
    if (getch() == 'g') {
        printw("You pressed G\n");
    }
    napms(500);
    printw("Running\n");
}
```

and it worked pretty well..then I turn to use `cout` to print what I read in `getch()`...
I am now confused how `nucurse.h` handle the `cout` or I mean standard I/O..?

Comment: when I use `cout`... It can not print...and shows some strange character...

Comment: Why not show the code that *doesn't* work?

Comment: `ncurses` puts the terminal into raw mode. `cin` and `cout` generally only work well in cooked mode.

Comment: yeah...I agreed.. thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`initscr` tells (n)curses to write to the standard output.  However, ncurses buffers its writes separately from the `cout` stream (see for example [*Output buffering*](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce.html#h3-lib-setbuf) in the ncurses6 release notes), and flushes its output when told to `refresh`.  `getch` does a `refresh` call as a side-effect.  There aren't other `refresh` calls in your example.

`ncurses` (like SVr4 curses) sets its **input** to *raw mode*, but that aspect is not related to your problem with `cout`.

Comment: Emmmm...I think the function in curse.h is far beyond my ability... but your answer is helpful...thx!

Comment: I would wonder that is there a way to read the input without `enter` key

Comment: try `man 2 select`